# Drupal 7: from pantheon to a Local environment

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pantheon

I have a website on `pantheon` I want to copy this website to local so I created a database and then from the backup of the database and using command line I was able to import the backup to the database created on local also I did a clone of the code by running the command `git clone` and then I copied the files using `sftp` on the console I can see some

```
mkdir : No such file or directory
```

but no error

At the end when I try to open the website it Opens with no error but also with no style no images just the content.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing to copy files from server. Which is in `site/default/files`. 
If you are unable to download the directory then check permission on server. 
By default Drupal stores all images and image styles in `sites/default/files` or you can change path for public and private file by `config>media>file system`.
If you have all images but they are not showing on front end then just update path on `config>media>file system` and save.